# How to move files to parent folder, until parent folder isn't the only file in the directory

Tags: windows, files-folders

I have a bunch of pictures in a folder

```
C:\Users\Home\Documents\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4
```

Which looks like this:

```
Documents:
├───Stuff
├───Music
├───Text
├───Folder1
│   └───Folder2
│        └───Folder3
│            └───Folder4
│                 └───picture1.png
│                 └───picture2.png
│                 └───picturex.png
```

Since Folders 1-3 have nothing but a folder in them, I'd like to delete them and move my files to:

```
Documents:
├───Stuff
├───Music
├───Text
├───Folder4
│   └───picture1.png
│   └───picture2.png
│   └───picturex.png
```

I'd like apply this to multiple folders, quickly. How could I achieve that?

Comment: If you want to do this automatically, you'll need a shell script that navigates a directory subtree, bottom up, testing the level above each current level and moving the lower level up as appropriate. This could probably be best expressed recursively. I don't do Windows (and I'm not very good at recursion), so I can't provide details.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to do:

Open cmd: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>>>type cmd>><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Paste these codes:

```
move %userprofile%\Documents\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4 %userprofile%\Documents\
rd %userprofile%\Documents\Folder1 /s /q
```

Job done.

Comment: This is even more effort than cuting, pasting and then deleting the folders by hand. I'd like to do this by selecting a folder and do this automatically to all folders inside of it if it makes sense.